# NLCD 2016 Data in QGIS

Tags: polygonize, nlcd

I am struggling to convert the NLCD 2016 data to a shapefile in a CRS of WGS 84. I have three problems (that I think are simple) that I would love some help with:

(1) It seems other's have the option to open a .tif file in QGIS, my NLCD data does not contain any .tif files, only a .img file.

(2) I've been trying to work with the raster (.img) file and it is not projecting where I want it to (see attached image in which the OpenStreetMap and NLCD_2016 file are in EPSG:4326 WGS 84 CRS). [image]

(3) And, finally I've been unsuccessful when trying to polygonize the raster which I've tried several different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Curve Number Generator Plugin. It can download NLCD data as Raster and vector.

To get data in WGS 84 set CRS of the input shape file as EPSG:4326

Comment: Thanks that plug-in seems to be exactly what I need. I am running into some errors executing the command though, I created my area boundary but am getting the following error: "OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer". For background, I drew a polygon on a new shapefile and the used the field calculator to compute the area. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you share screenshot? Also, that plugin can only perform on areas less than 500,000 acres

Comment: Yea, I've been wondering if I'm trying to apply this to too large of an area. 500,000 acres is way to small for what I'm thinking. @ar-siddiqui, do you know of another method for a larger scale?

Comment: how big is your area? you may use this plugin with a script or download the NLCD raster from NLCD website and then clip it and then polygonize

Comment: Area is about 16,500,000 acres. Downloading as a raster and the polygonize it is my plan but I'm still having troubles doing it in QGIS (as mentioned in original post).

Comment: Ok then, please make this a single question and ask other questions as separate question on SE. Then paste link in the comments. I can answer all.

Comment: Alright, here you go https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/400694/convert-nlcd-2016-raster-to-vector