# Convert NLCD 2016 Raster to Vector

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, nlcd

My goal is to create a .shp file in CRS EPSG 4326 - WGS 84 of land cover data for several counties in California. My idea is to use the NLCD 2016 dataset in QGIS to convert it into the desired shapefile. However, when I try to set all layers to WGS 84 (simply by clicking properties->source->and changing the drop down CRS (ignoring the warning that this will not change the original data)), the resulting image looks like this:

[image]

How can I get the NLCD data to overlay the OpenStreet basemap (set to WGS 84 in same manner as NLCD raster) correctly?

Comment: Maybe you should *not* ignore the warning

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/348525/107424

Comment: If my answer below solves your question then accept the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Setting CRS of a layer just by its properties does not reproject the layer. It does not change the underlying data (as the warning suggested, which you ignored). For example an XY point -8505413,3187458 (EPSG:3857) will not be changed to EPSG:4326 (WGS 84) equivalent (~ -75.48,26.66) but the QGIS will think that -8505413,3187458 is in EPSG:4326.

To reproject the NLCD Raster (change actual data), use GDAL WARP in QGIS.
[image]